# How to read data form EditTextPreference in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, sharedpreferences

I am trying to read data from EditTextPreference. Like below

> Preference.xml

```
<PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/driver_info">
    <EditTextPreference
        android:dialogTitle="@string/driver_name"
        android:key="driver_name"
        android:title="@string/driver_name" />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

> ConfigActivity.java

```
public class ConfigActivity extends PreferenceActivity implements OnPreferenceChangeListener {

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(ConfigActivity.this);

    final String driverName = prefs.getString("driver_name",  null);
    Log.d(TAG,"driverName-->"+driverName);
}
}
```

In the edit text i have entered aaaa and clicked OK button , but still receiving below log

ConfigActivity: driverName-->null

[image]

I just trying read the data from "test"(string). Please find attached screenshot for reference.

Can you please help me . How we will read editext string.

Comment: Post the code for the ok button as now we do not see hoe you try to read from the edittextpreference.

Comment: @blackapps I have modified the question. I have not written ID for ok button.

Comment: `How we will read editext string.` What do you mean? You did not post code that tries to read from edittext.

Comment: @blackapps  I am trying read "test" as shown in screen shot.

Comment: ? Where? Please show the code and tell when and where you try to read from an edittext. The only thing we see is that you try to read from shared preferences in onCreate. But nowhere from the edittext itself.

Comment: edittextpreference is new to me , I have tries some examples , it was written some like that. how can can read data. Do you have any examples?

Answer (score 1):

You can listen to changes with an *OnPreferenceChangeListener*. (I see that you have already implemented it in your class.) Then you can set the listener to your EditTextPreference like:

```
Preference driverNamePref = findPreference("driver_name")); //You can put this string key in string resources in fact
driverNamePref.setOnPreferenceChangeListener(this);
```

In the onPreferenceChange callback, you'll receive the new value entered by the user, so you can take a grasp of the new value and do whatever you want to do with that:

```
 @Override
 public boolean onPreferenceChange(Preference preference, Object newValue) {
  //Get the newValue and do what you want to do with it
    if (preference.getKey().equals("driver_name")) {
        String driverName = (String) newValue;
    ...
   }
 }
```

Note also that onPreferenceChange callback is called before the new value is actually saved in the sharedPreferences. So you can also make data validation here if you need to. If data is not valid, you can show an error and return false, so new value won't be saved. If everything is all right return true and it will be saved to SharedPreferences.